# Jquery UTF-8 Character Encoding

Tags: jquery, character-encoding

i have my get method using `jquery` that passes a variable which may contain Japanese characters. as i tested it, jquery doesn't allow the inputs with japanese characters eventhough i already used the `encodeURIComponent()`. below is my snippet:

```
function checkMediaPrefix(){
   var query = encodeURIComponent($('#mediaType :selected').text());
   var uri = 'nofilter/checkMediaPrefix/options?mediaType=' + query;

   alert(uri);

   $.get(uri, function(responseText){
   $('#mediaPrefix').text(responseText);
   $('input#mediaPrefText').val(responseText);
});
}
```

the error says Internal Server Error Status 500. please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me to resolve this problem. It turned out that i need also to change some configuration on my Tomcat Server (server.xml) in order to successfully get the Japanese character parameter.

http://tech.top21.de/techblog/20100421-solving-problems-with-request-parameter-encoding.html